# Why not maintain state in localStorage if redux loses state on refresh?

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

If the one of the solution to maintain a redux state is store it in localStorage, then . why not maintain the state in the localStorage instead.

Comment: Do you mean why even use Redux, and just do all the store stuff in localStorage?

Comment: using localstorage directly has some disadvantages. It can only store string, and accessing it is a bit slow when compared to accessing data from memory. So people just write to localstorage on data change in redux asynchronously, but since they read/write to memory, the operations are faster and can store data as we need. No need to parsing and then `stringify` every time to store in the localstorage

Answer (score 2):

You can totally do this. Dan Abramov (author of Redux) actually has [a lesson on persisting Redux state to local storage](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage).